# Calculated DataFrame column by a column condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new in Python and I'm trying to calculate a new column of a DataFrame based on a condition by another column of the same dataframe.

I have a DataFrame with the columns A, B, C, D, E.

I need to calculate new column F:

```
F = A - B if E == 'Y'
F = A - (C + D) if E == 'N'
```

I tried to use the function `Apply` but it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
def my_funcion(column): 
    if column == 'N' :
        return df['B']
    if column== 'Y' :
        return (df['C'] + df['D'])
df['F'] = df['A'] - df.apply(myfunction(df['E'], axis=1)
```

But it shows me this error:

> ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, 
>       a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', u'occurred at index 0'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

Solution if in `E` are only `Y` and `N` values:

```
np.random.seed(145)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10,size=(5,4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df['E'] = ['Y'] * 3 + ['N'] * 2 

df['F'] = np.where(df['E'] == 'Y', df['A'] - df['B'], df['A'] - (df['C'] + df['D']))
print (df)

   A  B  C  D  E   F
0  5  5  6  7  Y   0
1  2  5  8  5  Y  -3
2  1  2  0  8  Y  -1
3  4  5  8  9  N -13
4  1  6  7  6  N -12
```

Solution if in column `E` are not only `N` and `Y`:

```
np.random.seed(145)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10,size=(5,4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df['E'] = ['Y'] * 2 + ['N'] * 2  + ['X']

df['F'] = np.where(df['E'] == 'Y', df['A'] - df['B'], 
          np.where(df['E'] == 'N', df['A'] - (df['C'] + df['D']), 100))
print (df)

   A  B  C  D  E    F
0  5  5  6  7  Y    0
1  2  5  8  5  Y   -3
2  1  2  0  8  N   -7
3  4  5  8  9  N  -13
4  1  6  7  6  X  100
```

If want use `apply` (slowier):

```
def my_funcion(column): 
    if column['E'] == 'Y' :
        return column['B']
    if column['E'] == 'N' :
        return (column['C'] + column['D'])

df['F'] = df['A'] - df.apply(my_funcion, axis=1) 
print (df)

   A  B  C  D  E   F
0  5  5  6  7  Y   0
1  2  5  8  5  Y  -3
2  1  2  0  8  N  -7
3  4  5  8  9  N -13
4  1  6  7  6  N -12
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael, now it works...
But I need to define that funcion because I need to use it in different part of my code.
So, if i would like to define the funcion, how I can change my code?

Comment: Sorry, i edited my first comment because I need to ask you another question. Please read my first comment..

Comment: just a question.
If i would like to add a condition on another column, for example Column Z different from 0 (zero), I have to write:

np.where(df['E'] == 'Y' and df['Z'] != 0, df['A'] - df['B']) ???
But it shows an error.
Can you help me to write correctly?

Comment: Column Z is a Float64

Comment: You need `np.where(d(f['E'] == 'Y') & (df['Z'] != 0), df['A'] - df['B'], df['A'] - (df['C'] + df['D']))` for bitwise and.

Comment: What is the role of the word 'column' in the function?